# PHP variable can't be found

Tags: php, variables

When using this PHP code

```php
$random = 00000; //a random int
$gameCode = $random;
$players = 0; //An example number
echo "<h4>$players Players</h4>";

while(true) {
    sleep(1);
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM gamecode WHERE gamecode = '$gameCode'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows != $players) { 
        $players = $result->num_rows;
        echo "<h4>$players Players</h4>";
        flush();
    } 
}
```

I am 99% the variables cant be found as i get an error saying that it is not an object and it works when i define the variable in the while loop. (Which i cant do for reasons)

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /storage/ssd4/654/2919654/public_html/createcode.php on line (Lines trying to use $players and $gamecode)

Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I edited the post with the error

Comment: There is no issue with the variable scope. Here's the proof. https://repl.it/N4Fr .... The only thing to notice is your $random var. 0 or 0000 means the same if you want to put multiple zeros so make it to a string rather than int.

Comment: The random number is not 0000 is is a randomly generating number. I just didn't want the code to be unnecessarily longer.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that should be an object in there is $result, I expect that the query has failed and $result == false

When you call $result->num_rows that will fail with the error message you are seeing.

Try adding this test in

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Something broke');
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem, I said that the error is fixed when the variables are defined in the while loop. I'm asking how i can use variables inside the while loop that are outside the while loop.

Comment: There is nothing that stops a variable outside the loop being used in the loop. You have a different problem.